# tidyverse column names and backticks (sometimes yield escape character errors e.g. slashes)

Tags: r, dplyr, escaping, tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars %>% transmute(`cyl\abc` = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
#> # A tibble: 32 x 1
#>    `cyl\abc`
#>        <dbl>
#>  1         6
#>  2         6
#>  3         4
#>  4         6
#>  5         8
#>  6         6
#>  7         8
#>  8         4
#>  9         4
#> 10         6
#> # ... with 22 more rows
```

In the R tidyverse I was under the impression I can name a column almost anything, as long as I wrap the column name in backticks, as shown in the working example above.

However, if the column name is slightly modified, I sometimes get an error, as shown below:

```
mtcars %>% transmute(`cyl\cyl` = cyl) %>% as_tibble()
#> Error: '\c' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting "`cyl\c"
```

How could I name a column `cyl\cyl` without receiving the error above, and what is the reason for the error? In other words, why doesn't the top example yield an error something along the lines `'\a' is an unrecognized escape`?

Also note, that the column name has to be `cyl\cyl` as the output from R analysis is fed into another system requiring this `cyl\cyl` column. Unfortunately, simply renaming the column to "something better" won't work.

Comment: `transmute(\`cyl\\cyl\` = cyl)`. `\a` is actually creating a special character, not a \ that will export elsewhere, so you need to escape the \ with another one, even when doing `cyl\\abc`.

Comment: also, it is not anything specific to tidyverse, it is the usual behaviour of names/strings in R, a helpful example might be ```cat(names(c(`c\a` = 1, `c\\a` = 2, `c\\c` = 3, `c\n` = 4, `c\\n` = 5)))```

Comment: @caldwellst my attempt to get the column name `cyl\cyl` with escaping is ```mtcars %>% transmute(`cyl\\cyl` = cyl)``` and also ```mtcars %>% transmute(`cyl\\\\cyl` = cyl)```. These yield column names of `cyl\\cyl` and `cyl\\\\cyl`, respectively. How do I properly escape to get the column name `cyl\cyl`?

Comment: It only appeals as `cyl\\cyl` within R, export and you will see it is correct. Export `cyl\abc` to see that it is wrong.

Comment: @caldwellst and that is the answer I was looking for. problem solved.